# Automatic "fancy" comment insertion with Vim

Tags: vim, vi

I like to have comments like this in my C code:

```
/********************************************************
 * Blah
 ********************************************************/
```

But I get tired of typing all those asterisks, and copy/pasting can also get annoying. I was wondering if I could possibly create a macro with Vim so that if I press (for example) `CTRL+L`, it'll automatically insert that structure in my code and align the cursor in the middle (where the actual comment is written).

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: reading them gets annoying too, IMHO :)

Comment: @Peter: True, but it's nice to have a clear distinction in your code. It creates a nice separation in my opinion. But I certainly agree that having too many of them gets really annoying as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [snipmate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540), a vim plugin for TextMate-like snippets.

- https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate
- 1min screencast: http://vimeo.com/3535418

> snipMate.vim implements some of TextMate's snippets features in Vim. A
>   snippet is a piece of often-typed text that you can insert into your
>   document using a trigger word followed by a <tab>.

Comment: Oh man, this looks like exactly what I want. I'll install it and see if it works!

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you so much for letting me know about this plugin, @miku. Do you know of any other such-extremely-useful plugins for Vim?

Comment: @Amit, glad to be of help. No I have no other plugin recommendation at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

If you are planning to go on snipmate (which IMHO is a good choice!), you should consider using the version maintained by [Garbas on github](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) (pay attention to the required plugins in the readme file).
The version from msanders is no longer maintained.

Since I am new  I can't add a comment to the answer above... Sorry

Answer (score 2):

You can use [cvim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213), and edit `~/.vim/c-support/templates/c.comments.template` to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Heh, just today I was beefing up my own support for this (as these headers are mandated by company coding standard).

```
iabbrev //== // (96 equal characters)<Enter>//<Enter>// (96 equal characters)<C-O>k
iabbrev //-- // (96 dashes)<Enter>//<Enter>// (96 dashes)<C-O>k
```

These allow me to type //== and when I press space the whole thing is entered and I'm left with the cursor "in the middle" where I want it.

So- for the OP, if you want to use Ctrl-L, do something like this:

```
inoremap <C-L> /*****<Enter> * <Enter>*****<C-O>k
```

(I like abbreviations myself, though...)

Since there are other points in our coding standard where we need to extend dashes and equals out to column 100, I whipped this up today:

```
iabbrev <expr> === InsertTo99Width('===')
iabbrev <expr> --- InsertTo99Width('---')

function! InsertTo99Width(insertion)
    let l:line = getline('.')
    let l:linelen = strlen(l:line)
    let l:col = col('.')
    let l:numchars = (99 - col)

    let l:inserted = a:insertion
    if (l:linelen <= l:col) && (l:numchars > 0)
        let l:numchars += len(l:inserted)
        while len(l:inserted) < l:numchars
            let l:inserted = l:inserted . l:inserted
        endwhile
        return l:inserted[0 : l:numchars]
    else
        return l:inserted
    endif
endfunction
```

(I'm sort of a vim scripting newb so there may be an easier way to make a string of N characters long, but this allows arbitrary strings of arbitrary length to be repeated so if you like dash-space-equal-space or something, it'll still look "nice".)

Anyway finally- you can use `<expr>` in the inoremap too if you want, so you can make your asterisks go to a set width based on the output of a function.  There's a lot of power in there, but it may take some fiddling to get it just the way you want...