# How to can I make a title shortcut

Tags: vim

I use vim and I want that in every file I will have a title like

```
 **year=
 **author=
 **
 **
```

..
I want to map a key for past it in the head of a file.
Their is any plugin for this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatic "fancy" comment insertion with Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081643/automatic-fancy-comment-insertion-with-vim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't need a plugin just to map a key to insert some text at the beginning of the current buffer:

```
:nno \h ggO**year=<cr>**author=<cr>**<cr>**<esc>
```

Just change `\h` to your
preferred key sequence.

Answer (score 0):

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.